# Python - Incremential chain of numbers not working fine

Tags: python

I have a program that takes three numbers as command line arguments. It should then display a list of numbers that differ by the same amount as the first two, with the length of the list being the third number.

My current code does not work when the difference between the first two inputs is negative or zero.

Here are three test cases:

1. This works (but the sum is wrong):

   ```
   python suite.py 1 2 10  
   > 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 56
   ```

   sum should be `55`.
2. This fails:

   ```
   python suite.py 30 27 8
   > 0
   ```

   the output should be

   ```
   > 30 27 24 21 18 15 12 9 = 156
   ```
3. This fails:

   ```
   python suite.py 6 6 6
   > 6
   ```

   the output should be

   ```
   > 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 36
   ```

Here's the code:

```
import sys

def suite(premier, second, nombre):
    message = ""
    message2 = ""
    if second < premier:
        diff = (premier - second) * -1
    else:
        diff = second - premier
    maximum = premier + (diff * nombre)
    i = premier
    total = premier
    for i in range(premier, maximum, diff):
        message += str(i) + " + "
        message2 = message[:-3]
        total += i
    message2 += " = " + str(i)
    return message2

def main():
    premier = int(sys.argv[1])
    second = int(sys.argv[2])
    nombre = int(sys.argv[3])
    if premier == second:
        resultat = premier
    else:
        resultat = suite(premier, second, nombre)
    print(resultat)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "I've tried to add exceptions but it doesn't work well all the time" Show us the code that has the exceptions you added, and show us the times that it didn't work well. Explain what output you expected to get, and what output you got instead.

Comment: i've updated my post thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10` is `55`, not `56`

Comment: OP, please let me know if my edits are correct and acceptable.

Comment: Thats perfect!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more Pythonic alternative :

```
import sys 

def suite(premier, second, nombre):
    diff = second - premier
    if diff == 0:
        nombres = [premier] * nombre
    else:
        maximum = premier + diff * nombre
        nombres = range(premier, maximum, diff)
    gauche = ' + '.join(map(str, nombres))
    droite = sum(nombres)
    return '%s = %d' % (gauche, droite)

def main():
    premier = int(sys.argv[1])
    second = int(sys.argv[2])
    nombre = int(sys.argv[3])
    print(suite(premier, second, nombre))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For `1 2 10`, it outputs:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55
```

For `30 27 8`:

```
30 + 27 + 24 + 21 + 18 + 15 + 12 + 9 = 156
```

For `6 6 6`:

```
6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 36
```

Comment: Try `suite(6, 6, 6)`. I just added an addendum for that.

Comment: Also, remove `premier, second = sorted([premier, second])`. It's the exact opposite of what OP wants.

Comment: It's not. OP has three test cases with desired outputs. Please run all of them.

Comment: Here's a summary: `6 6 6 -> 6 6 6 6 6 6`, `1 2 10 -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, `30 27 8 -> 30 27 24 21 18 15 12 9`

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. I edited it to fix the language, but hopefully didn't touch anything that matters.

Comment: Very clean solution. I like it. I just hope I didn't misinterpret the whole question :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole mess of things that can be fixed in your code. Starting from the top:

- You never need to check `if second < premier`: `diff = (premier - second) * -1` is exactly equivalent to `diff = second - premier`. Just remove the `if` completely and always use `diff = second - premier`.
- The initialization `i = premier` is unnecessary, and confuses your code later on. Remove it.
- `total = premier` should be `total = 0`. You will add `premier` in the first iteration of the loop.
- `message2 = message[:-3]` should be moved out of the loop. It just chops off the last `+`, which only needs to be done once. In fact, there is no need to have a separate variable for `message2` since it is only used once for that purpose.
- `message2 += " = " + str(i)` should be `message2 += " = " + str(total)`. Given the above, you can just write `message = message[:-3] + " = " + str(total)` and return `message` instead of `message2`.

One final point. The reason that `6 6 6` does not work is that `range` will do nothing if the step size is zero. You need to either have a special case for when `diff == 0` or move away from using `range` entirely. I would recommend the latter option for two reasons. First, it keeps the code simpler because you don't have special cases. Second, it makes is so you don't have to compute the maximum value any more. Here is a sample of the loop:

```
total = 0
num = premier
while nombre > 0:
    message += str(num) + " + "
    nombre -= 1
    num += diff
```

Of course you need to remove the check for `premier == second` in `main`.